# Relative strength of a dome

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, geometry, statics

Is there a rough way to determine how the height of a dome affects the load that dome could support? For instance, assuming the bases of two domes are 24" in diameter, and one dome is 2" high while the other is 4" high. Is there a way to understand how much stronger the 2nd one is compared to the first one?

Comment: What do you mean by "load that dome could support"? Point load? Uniform surface loading? Ratio of yield strength of the material that would just be capable of supporting the dome's own weight without collapse? What assumptions are you making about the (relative) shape of the domes, the thickness of the material, the fraction of the "strength" of the dome used to support itself, ... as it is, this question is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: Sorry for being so vague. Not sure I'll be able to address all your questions.

Comment: I've been making a type of archtop guitar. But instead of carving the soundboards out of a thick piece of wood, I'm making them from thin slats of wood, bent and glued together to form a (guitar-shaped) section of a dome (a dome with a 5.5' radius).

Comment: The strings of a guitar like this are attached at the peg head at one end, and to the tail piece at the other, passing over the bridge at the center of the soundboard (just like on a violin). In my case, the arch of this soundboard dome is .75" from neck block to tail block. The string's tension creates downward force on the bridge, in my case, around 35 lb of it.

I guess that would be a point load?

Comment: Anyway, if the only thing that changed was the radius of the dome (making an arch twice as high, for instance), I'm wondering if there is a way of knowing that the second dome is X-times stronger? Or if the arch of the dome is half as high, that this decreases the "strength" of the dome by X amount? 

Sort of like the relative strength of beams that are the same width but of different heights, where the cube of the heights of two beams indicates the strength of one relative to the other.

Comment: That is much clearer. There are two things to consider: buckling, or collapse because the support at the base of the done fails. Not sure that there is a simple "formula". Is your "dome" basically a section of a sphere with constant shell thickness, variable radius of curvature, and fixed boundary condition ("base" of "done" constant)? Because that might be an answerable question.

Comment: I suggest you edit your clarification into the question - then I can upvote it.

Comment: Yes, it is a (guitar-shaped) section of a sphere with a constant shell thickness, and fixed boundary. There is no variable radius of curvature, only the single, fixed-radius of the section of the sphere that the soundboard conforms to.

Comment: Maybe a picture would make it clearer:

https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/t1.0-9/542561_4340836676929_1706302960_n.jpg

Comment: Yes, there is a way. It is called statics, and it is taught in 2nd, 3rd year of engineering school.

Answer (score 1):

The study you are looking at is falls under *loaded annular disks and flat round plates* with references [**here**](http://www.codecogs.com/library/engineering/materials/circular-plates.php) and [**here**](http://www.roymech.co.uk/Useful_Tables/Mechanics/Plates.html) as well as the venerable Roark formulas for Stress book. Structural engineers design domes all the time and [**here**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/98217984/Design-of-Circular-Domes) is a reference to their calculations. They seem to like [Conoidal Domes](http://books.google.com/books?id=TVmUCXBrVe8C&lpg=PR8&ots=5jVbY9l_Qb&dq=conoidal%20domes%20structures&pg=PA273#v=onepage&q=conoidal%20domes%20structures&f=false).

However adding the complication of a curved plate, or dome shaped, is doable analytically, yet very complex to carry out. Even for the flat plates the formulas are quite involved.

So at this stage you are left to do a more thorough web search for thin dome stress values, and I am left with some notes from engineering experience:

1. If the dome is flat, then any vertical load is going to tend to pull-in the supports causing tensile stresses near the edges of the dome, as well as near the center where the load is applied.
2. When curvature is added, additional compressive stresses are added near the supports canceling out the tensile stresses making the structure stronger.
3. When the curvature is too much (dome is too high) you are going to start to push out the material at the supports making it weaker.

So there is an optimal dome shape, but calculating it for any real life case is going to be challenging. If you are serious about it, you can either conducts tests of different designs, or hire an engineering consultant to do a Finite Element Analysis design study to find the optimal design. Check your local university, as they seems to have an abundance of grad students with nothing to do in general.

---

*BTW:* Have you considered a conical shape which is going to be stronger than a curved shape when a single load is applied?